# C# code to monitor a CVS repository for changes

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-integration, cvs

Is there a way to monitor a CVS repository for any commits?

Then on a commit, to download all the files within the changeset, along with their respective paths within the repository?

The reason is, I want to set up continuous integration between a CVS repository and a development server, which can only be accessed via FTP.

Before uploading, I also want to run all the files through compressors/processors.

So is the above possible with C#?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the standard way of doing such things is to run something on the [post commit hook](http://pragmaticautomation.com/cgi-bin/pragauto.cgi/Monitor/LettingCVSPullTheTrigger.rdoc/style/print) (either your application or a something to send a message to your application).

The other option is polling. A quick good shows this [library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpcvslib/) to access CVS in .NET, which can also be used to do the second part of your requirements.

Just one quick point on this, most CI servers will handle the polling/notification for you. Or have I miss understood the requirements?